# how to find usage of a dependency in a pom

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am working on a maven project, there is a dependency in the pom added, but I don't know where it is used in the code, so if it is not used I want to delete it.
so how can I tell where this dependency is used?

note that the dependency I am mentioning is under

its name is maven-assembly-plugin

Comment: A plugin is not a dependency. Plugins are not used "in the code", but during the build. The assembly plugin is usually configured to create a fat jar or a zip.

Comment: yes you're right, I got confused because I am getting this error:

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4 in nexus-xyz-plugin (inaternal repo link)

Comment: any idea about this error? @JFabianMeier

Comment: Sorry, but this a different question, please ask a new question on Stackoverflow.